# Replace variables in array with data in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some question about javascript.
I need to create a autosort feature, by different time interval, on my page.
User can select time interval by picking a checkbox. The data on rows updates every 3 seconds, and autosort need to fire every 20 seconds.

This part of code is run when user check time interval, and return the value in array *["percent_10s", "percent_30s", "percent_1m"]*.
The user can pick one or multiple time interval.

```
function update_sort() {
   $('#sort_form :checked').each(function() {
      sort_vals.push($(this).val());
   });
   return sort_vals;
};
$('#sort_form').change(update_sort);
```

Another part of my code store the percent data, and update this value every 3 sec for every document.

```
var percent_10s = 10;
var percent_30s = 12;
var percent_1m = 15;
```

How i can calculate this, by passing the array of variables from first part, to do this. Let say, User pick *percent_10s* and *percent_30s*, i need get the sum of this variable in the loop for every document, and save this value to div with this: .attr('data-percent', percents_grow).
Then on web page **Tinysort** make a sort by data-percent attribut.

Data updates every 3 sec, and i want to get every 20 sec document with max percents_grow value, let say for 10 sec, on for 10sec+1minute. I just need to pick this with checkbox, and then get result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object for the variables so you can use the array values to get associated value from same property name in object

```js
//array from checkboxes by calling update_sort()
var sort_vals = ['percent_10s', 'percent_1m']

// object to look up values
var percents = {
  percent_10s: 10,
  percent_30s: 12,
  percent_1m: 15
};

// reduce to get sum
var sum = sort_vals.reduce(function(a, c){
   return a + percents[c]; 
},0);

console.log(sum)// expect 25 from percents.percent_10s + percents.percent_1m
```

Answer (score 0):

@Charlietfi method worked perfect, but i get another problem, with var.
I put this function in the beginning of document.

```
var checked_sort = [];
function update() {
   $('#sort_form :checked').each(function() {
      checked_sort.push($(this).val());
   });
};

$('#sort_form').change(update);
```

And if I put `var checked_sort = [];` like this, i get duplicate, because function pushes new data to array without cleaning previous entries.

```
["percent_5m", "percent_5m", "percent_10m", "percent_1m", "percent_5m", "percent_10m"]
```

If I put `var checked_sort = [];` inside the function, Array is Ok, but next function did not see the Array, because ***checked_sort not defined***.

Comment: I find the solution using this inside the function: `checked_sort.length = 0;`